# embedded web browser

Tags: linux, user-interface, browser, embedded, embedded-linux

I'm looking for Linux embedded web browser, or preferably just a rendering object (it will not be used for actual browsing, just for displaying web based gui). 
The requirements are:

1. Written in C/C++ (small footprint)
2. Support Dynamic HTML
3. Support Java script
4. Minimum dependencies on the libraries (although i understand that it can not be completely standalone)
5. No Dependency on X11 (i.e working with direct frame qui libraries)

So far i only found [Embedded Konqueror](http://www.basyskom.de/index.pl/konqe). Any suggestions are welcomed, commercial solutions are OK, but open source is preferable.

Found another option [QT WebKit](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/QtWebKit) which is selected and answers all my requirements.

Another update: Successfully installed and tested embedded QT distribution with WebKit on my board. The configuration of frame buffer was seamless, touch screen calibration took some time, but on the bottom line everything working as expected.
And I'm entering wonderful world of java script :) I  handle much better kernel drivers.

Another update: I found another commercial solution that i might consider in the future. 
embedded browser from access company [here](http://www.access-company.com/products/mobile_solutions/netfrontmobile/browser/index.html). I did not worked with them, but it was recommend so for public record i put it here as well.

Comment: I am in a very similar situation.  Please let us know which solution fits your needs best!

Comment: Do you have Display also in your set up or you want to access Web GUI on remote system over network? In later case, You can just use some web server like boa, lighttpd etc.

Answer (score 4):

You may try out the Chromium Embedded Framework(CEF). It has C and C++ interface with bindings for several other languages (Python, .NET, Java).

https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/

If you would like to use as much Javascript as possible, you can try node-webKit (Uses CEF under the hood). Within node-webkit you use nodeJS(serverside javascript) libraries directly from the DOM.

https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit

Answer (score 1):

You may try to build WebKit with DirectFB version of GTK+.

Another alternative is [Firefox on DirectFB](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/DFBPorting) but it seems not ready yet.

Comment: I think that if you can find all the right versions of stuff it does in fact work... the problem is that relatively few people care about DirectFB support in GTK/Mozilla/etc so it tends to be out of date/broken/old and the wiki pages never seem to change...

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't hit all of your requirements, but have you considered Prism: http://prism.mozillalabs.com/

Comment: thanks, but i can not drop any of my requirements except (4) that it's kind of vague ...

Comment: Thanks, i added c++ as well i meant i don't want java and alike.

Comment: No longer developed: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Prism

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can do what you want with [Xulrunner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xulrunner) ?

You can certainly make it start up a window with a web page which can then do "stuff" using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't say it needs to be free, [Opera for Linux Devices](http://www.opera.com/business/solutions/devices/) is pretty much exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: i had a discussion with Opera in the past as well, it's quite expensive and does not have an evaluation option so i dropped it. As i stated i'm using QT with WebKit and Frame-buffer option works pretty good.